# CountDownTimer in EditText lag in the last second

Tags: android

I would like to set an `EditText` with a timer thanks to `CountDownTimer`.
My EditText write second by second the number 3 and 2 but for the 1 there is a lag (it take 1,5 to 2 seconds).
Maybe I do it wrong.

This is my code :

```
CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                txt_timer.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                txt_timer.setText("GO");
            }
        };
        mCountDownTimer.start();
```

Comment: your code looks correct may be the memory in device causing the problem

Comment: I have the same prob! the reason is your device

Comment: I have a very good device. It's strange... There's not an other solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory in the device cause the problem. I found a solution running a new thread.

I have to declare `int i=4;` before and use this code :

```
new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (i-- > 1) {
                    try {
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                txt_timer.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                txt_timer.setText("GO");
            }
        }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the UI thread is doing too much work. Try running a new thread on the UI thread itself:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            //Insert your code
        }
    });
}
```

Let me know if you can;t get this to work!